# MongoDB with Virtual box replica set setup on Ubuntu 0.8 connection problem

Tags: centos, virtualbox, mongodb, ubuntu-8.04

I'm trying to build a mongo replica set on my server, Centos 5.6, that would be setup from 5 VB holding Ubuntu 8.10 and mongodb. The main problem is i can't connect to mongo on virtual box.

The network is setup over NAT with forwarded ports.

I have my image of Ubuntu 8.1. Below the way I create a box

```
VBoxManage createvm --name "mongovb_03" --ostype Ubuntu --register
VBoxManage modifyvm "mongovb_03" --memory 2048 --acpi on --boot1 dvd --nic1 nat
VBoxManage modifyvm "mongovb_03" --pae on --cpus 2 
VBoxManage storagectl "mongovb_03" --name "SATA Controller" --add sata --controller IntelAhci
VBoxManage storageattach "mongovb_03" --storagectl "SATA Controller" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium "ubuntu_8.vdi"
```

Than I forward port using vboxtool.

```
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-tcp-2003-2812/GuestPort, Value: 2812
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-tcp-2003-2812/HostPort, Value: 2003
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-tcp-2003-2812/Protocol, Value: TCP
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-tcp-2023-22/GuestPort, Value: 22
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-tcp-2023-22/HostPort, Value: 2023
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-tcp-2023-22/Protocol, Value: TCP
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-tcp-27003-27017/GuestPort, Value: 27017
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-tcp-27003-27017/HostPort, Value: 27003
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-tcp-27003-27017/Protocol, Value: TCP
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-tcp-28003-28017/GuestPort, Value: 28017
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-tcp-28003-28017/HostPort, Value: 28003
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-tcp-28003-28017/Protocol, Value: TCP
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-tcp-8083-80/GuestPort, Value: 80
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-tcp-8083-80/HostPort, Value: 8083
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-tcp-8083-80/Protocol, Value: TCP
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-udp-2003-2812/GuestPort, Value: 2812
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-udp-2003-2812/HostPort, Value: 2003
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-udp-2003-2812/Protocol, Value: UDP
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-udp-2023-22/GuestPort, Value: 22
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-udp-2023-22/HostPort, Value: 2023
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-udp-2023-22/Protocol, Value: UDP
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-udp-27003-27017/GuestPort, Value: 27017
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-udp-27003-27017/HostPort, Value: 27003
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-udp-27003-27017/Protocol, Value: UDP
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-udp-28003-28017/GuestPort, Value: 28017
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-udp-28003-28017/HostPort, Value: 28003
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-udp-28003-28017/Protocol, Value: UDP
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-udp-8083-80/GuestPort, Value: 80
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-udp-8083-80/HostPort, Value: 8083
Key: VBoxInternal/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/vboxtool-udp-8083-80/Protocol, Value: UDP
```

So now I can have access my vbox via ssh like that:

```
ssh -p 2023 localhost
```

I can also access my apache on **localhost:8083** or munin on **http://localhost:8083/munin/index.html**

The problem is that I can't access mongo.

My mongo.conf

```
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

 logappend=true

 port=27017
 journal=true
 bind_ip=127.0.0.1
```

So when I try to connect to mongo I get:

```
mongo 127:0.0.1:27003
MongoDB shell version: 1.8.1
connecting to: 127:0.0.1:27003/test
Wed Sep 21 14:33:31 getaddrinfo("127:0.0.1") failed: nodename nor servname provided, or         not known
Wed Sep 21 14:33:31 Error shell/mongo.js:81
exception: connect failed
```

Or:

```
mongo localhost:27003
MongoDB shell version: 1.8.1
connecting to: localhost:27003/test
Wed Sep 21 14:34:04 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Wed Sep 21 14:34:04 terminate() called in shell, printing stack:
0x2947 0x960d717a 0x960d71ba 0x960d72b8 0xbd752 0xe651d 0xf0777 0x2c9a0 0x14b0e4     0x1c960f 0x1cae2b 0x1d4e93 0x1c9fe5 0x18b379 0x18b2d0 0x18b1da 0x15598f 0x214da 0x13b979 0x9b82 
 0   mongo                               0x00002947 _Z11myterminatev + 103
 1   libstdc++.6.dylib                   0x960d717a _ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE + 10
 2   libstdc++.6.dylib                   0x960d71ba _ZN10__cxxabiv112__unexpectedEPFvvE + 0
 3   libstdc++.6.dylib                   0x960d72b8 _ZL23__gxx_exception_cleanup19_Unwind_Reason_CodeP17_Unwind_Exception + 0
 4   mongo                               0x000bd752 _ZN5mongo9uassertedEiPKc + 210
 5   mongo                               0x000e651d _ZN5mongo17DBClientInterface7findOneERKSsRKNS_5QueryEPKNS_7BSONObjEi + 1325
 6   mongo                               0x000f0777 _ZN5mongo20DBClientWithCommands10runCommandERKSsRKNS_7BSONObjERS3_i + 119
 7   mongo                               0x0002c9a0 _ZN5mongo10shellUtils9onConnectERNS_20DBClientWithCommandsE + 496
 8   mongo                               0x0014b0e4 _ZN5mongo26mongo_external_constructorEP9JSContextP8JSObjectjPlS4_ + 388
 9   mongo                               0x001c960f js_Invoke + 3275
 10  mongo                               0x001cae2b js_InvokeConstructor + 702
 11  mongo                               0x001d4e93 js_Interpret + 40685
 12  mongo                               0x001c9fe5 js_Execute + 774
 13  mongo                               0x0018b379 JS_EvaluateUCScriptForPrincipals + 167
 14  mongo                               0x0018b2d0 JS_EvaluateUCScript + 67
 15  mongo                               0x0018b1da JS_EvaluateScript + 108
 16  mongo                               0x0015598f _ZN5mongo7SMScope4execERKNS_10StringDataERKSsbbbi + 511
 17  mongo                               0x000214da _ZN5mongo10shellUtils9initScopeERNS_5ScopeE + 282
 18  mongo                               0x0013b979 _ZN5mongo12ScriptEngine8newScopeEv + 41
 19  mongo                               0x00009b82 _Z5_mainiPPc + 4850
```

And this is my mongo log on virtual box:

```
cat mongodb.log
Wed Sep 21 14:12:51 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=5033 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit 
Wed Sep 21 14:12:51 [initandlisten] db version v1.8.3, pdfile version 4.5
Wed Sep 21 14:12:51 [initandlisten] git version: c206d77e94bc3b65c76681df5a6b605f68a2de05
Wed Sep 21 14:12:51 [initandlisten] build sys info: Linux bs-linux64.10gen.cc 2.6.21.7-2.ec2.v1.2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Nov 20 17:48:28 EST 2009 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_41
Wed Sep 21 14:12:51 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
Wed Sep 21 14:12:51 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Wed Sep 21 14:12:51 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Wed Sep 21 14:12:51 [websvr] web admin interface listening on port 28017
Wed Sep 21 14:13:51 [dur] lsn set 59540
Wed Sep 21 14:14:51 [dur] lsn set 119480
Wed Sep 21 14:15:45 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:48081 #1
Wed Sep 21 14:15:45 [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:48081
Wed Sep 21 14:15:51 [dur] lsn set 179021
Wed Sep 21 14:16:51 [dur] lsn set 238991
Wed Sep 21 14:17:02 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:48082 #2
Wed Sep 21 14:17:08 [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:48082
Wed Sep 21 14:17:51 [dur] lsn set 298802
Wed Sep 21 14:18:45 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55467 #3
Wed Sep 21 14:18:45 [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:55467
Wed Sep 21 14:18:51 [dur] lsn set 358133
Wed Sep 21 14:19:51 [dur] lsn set 418033
Wed Sep 21 14:20:51 [dur] lsn set 477573
Wed Sep 21 14:21:45 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55478 #4
Wed Sep 21 14:21:45 [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:55478
Wed Sep 21 14:21:51 [dur] lsn set 537524
Wed Sep 21 14:22:51 [dur] lsn set 597514
Wed Sep 21 14:23:51 [dur] lsn set 657484
Wed Sep 21 14:24:45 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53699 #5
Wed Sep 21 14:24:45 [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:53699
Wed Sep 21 14:24:51 [dur] lsn set 717465
Wed Sep 21 14:25:51 [dur] lsn set 777015
Wed Sep 21 14:26:51 [dur] lsn set 836945
Wed Sep 21 14:27:45 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53710 #6
Wed Sep 21 14:27:45 [conn6] end connection 127.0.0.1:53710
Wed Sep 21 14:27:51 [dur] lsn set 896856
Wed Sep 21 14:28:51 [dur] lsn set 956696
Wed Sep 21 14:29:51 [dur] lsn set 1016546
Wed Sep 21 14:30:45 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:42644 #7
Wed Sep 21 14:30:45 [conn7] end connection 127.0.0.1:42644
Wed Sep 21 14:30:51 [dur] lsn set 1075887
Wed Sep 21 14:31:51 [dur] lsn set 1135717
Wed Sep 21 14:32:51 [dur] lsn set 1195657
Wed Sep 21 14:33:45 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51476 #8
Wed Sep 21 14:33:45 [conn8] end connection 127.0.0.1:51476
Wed Sep 21 14:33:51 [dur] lsn set 1255638
Wed Sep 21 14:34:51 [dur] lsn set 1315568
Wed Sep 21 14:35:51 [dur] lsn set 1375048
Wed Sep 21 14:36:45 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51487 #9
Wed Sep 21 14:36:45 [conn9] end connection 127.0.0.1:51487
Wed Sep 21 14:36:51 [dur] lsn set 1435019
Wed Sep 21 14:37:51 [dur] lsn set 1495029
Wed Sep 21 14:38:51 [dur] lsn set 1555019
Wed Sep 21 14:39:45 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:46313 #10
Wed Sep 21 14:39:45 [conn10] end connection 127.0.0.1:46313
Wed Sep 21 14:39:51 [dur] lsn set 1614990
Wed Sep 21 14:40:51 [dur] lsn set 1674480
Wed Sep 21 14:41:51 [dur] lsn set 1734470
Wed Sep 21 14:42:45 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:46324 #11
Wed Sep 21 14:42:45 [conn11] end connection 127.0.0.1:46324
Wed Sep 21 14:42:51 [dur] lsn set 1794451
```

### Thanks for all the help, I'm really stuck here.

Marek.B

Answer (score 3):

Check your mongodb.conf (on ubuntu: /etc/mongodb.conf, not sure where on CentOS) and see if:

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

If so, comment that line with "#":

```
#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

Note that this may have security repercussions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the issue is but this certainly sticks out at me

```
getaddrinfo("127:0.0.1")
```

Shouldn't that be 127.0.0.1?